# OnSuccess script inside my Ajax.BeginForm is passing wrong data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on an as.net mvc web application. I have the following Ajax.BeginForm:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddServerToRack", "Server", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "result",
    LoadingElementId = "progressdialog",
    HttpMethod= "POST"
    ,
    OnSuccess = "addserver",
    OnFailure = "createfail"




}))
{
```

which calls the following action method:-

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Server")]
        [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "NoCache")]
        public ActionResult AddServerToRack(AddServerToRack s)
        {


            try
            {
                //code goes here
                repository.Save();

                return Json(new { IsSuccess = true, Update="",description = "Server Added Successfully.",rackid = s.rackID }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException exception)
            {


                return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, description = "Record was Modified by another User." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);




            }

            catch (DbUpdateException exception)
            {

                string error = String.IsNullOrEmpty(exception.InnerException.InnerException.Message) ? exception.InnerException.ToString() : exception.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToString();
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, description = "Error occurred." + error }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, description = "Error occurred." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }



        }
```

and the following OnSuccess script:-

```
function addserver(data) {
    if (data.IsSuccess = true) {

        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Rack/RackServer',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                id: data.rackid
            },

            dataType:'html' ,
            //error: function (xhr) {
            //    alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            //},
            success: function (result) {
                $('#RackDetails').html(result);
                $('#progress').hide();
            },

        });

        jAlert(data.description, 'Creation Confirmation');
    }
    else if (data.IsSuccess = false)
    {
        jAlert(data.description,'Error');

    }
}
```

but the problem i am facing is that the the `$.ajax({` call inside the script, will execute even if the data.IsSuccess value is false .So it seems that the script will not execution the if statement check and will always execute the Ajax call even if the IsSuccess does not equal true . 
so can anyone advice ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is wrong:

```
if (data.IsSuccess = true)
```

it should be:

```
if (data.IsSuccess == true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You used **"="** instead of **"=="** for comparing in you **addserver() method**

Use like below

```
if (data.IsSuccess == true)
```

or simple

```
    if (data.IsSuccess)
```